# Проблемы с MapActivity: Error inflating class

Tags: android, java

```
package test.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;

public class TestAndrActivity extends MapActivity{

    private MapView mapView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
}
```

-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical" 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent">

 <com.google.android.maps.MapView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/map_view"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:clickable="true" 
  android:enabled="true" 
  android:apiKey="MY_API_KEY" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Дает ошибку:

> `E/AndroidRuntime(361): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{test.test/test.test.TestAndrActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class com.google.android.maps.MapView`

и не толька эту... В манифесте включено:

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Может кто сталкивался. Буду очень благодарен.

Answer (score 2):

Уберите

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android
```

в 9 строчке.

Comment: убрал.

Ошибки:


04-13 04:45:11.117: E/AndroidRuntime(595): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-13 04:45:11.117: E/AndroidRuntime(595): java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Class ref in pre-verified class resolved to unexpected implementation
04-13 04:45:11.117: E/AndroidRuntime(595):  at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(Native Method)
04-13 04:45:11.117: E/AndroidRuntime(595):  at dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(DexFile.java:207)
04-13 04:45:11.117: E/AndroidRuntime(595):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:200)
...
...
...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621163/cannot-resolve-mapactivity-class-on-android

Comment: спасибо за ссылку - был там, не помогло(

Comment: я с таким не сталкивался, но понял,что проблема изза конфликта какого-то, потому проверь еще раз все или поменяй либу...

Comment: какую либу поменять?

Comment: может быть проблема с ключом?

Answer (score 0):

Очень похоже на то, что эмулятор не поддерживает Google Map API. Создайте эмулятор (AVD) где таргетом выбран "Google APIs"

[image: AVD on Google APIs]

Comment: все уровни google API пробувал. все то же

Answer (score 0):

В AndroidManifest.xml в теге **application** пропишите **uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"**

Если не поможет то сделайте **Project - Clean**

[Тут руководство](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html) если делать все как написано, то работает. Просто будьте внимательней